# Swift/Cocoa NSOutlineView. Single column, multiple cells. How to add things to different cells with bindings?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to get an NSOutlineView working with bindings (mostly because pretty much everything else in my app uses bindings, although if I can't achieve what I need I guess I'll have to go with the delegate/datasource method), and so far I've managed to get a basic view to display two levels.

My problem is, I want to have the levels display in different NSTableCellViews; with a delegate that appears to be trivial, but I cannot find a way to make it work with bindings. If I assign identifiers to the cells, I cannot find how to add things to them (and if I add identifiers to all but one, the items all get added to the one on Auto). If I leave all on auto, no matter how many children I add, they're all represented using the first kind of cell.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "add things"? If you want an outline view with different cell views for each level, check out the [TableViewPlayground Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: By "add things", I mean actually have the content show up. If the table cell views have an identifier (instead of being set to "automatic"), bindings will skip over that cellview and add items to the first view set to "automatic). I've (not really, but getting the job done) managed to fix it by adding "hidden" bindings to the differing elements of the cellview (i.e. images and whatnot) and putting everything an NSStackView with "Detach hidden views" on.

Comment: Assigning identifiers to the cell views shouldn't be a problem. Assign an identifier to the table column and implement the delegate's `viewForTableColumn` to create the cell view of your choice.

Comment: As I said, I was trying to do it (if at all possible) without a delegate. Nevertheless, it appears my approach with NSStackView and bindings to Hidden/Font/etc are good enough to define create different styles.